# Ways for a retired US citizen to spend more than ninety days in Austria?

Tags: visa, us-citizens, austria

Web pages that talk about visas for Austria tend to tell me how to get the type of visa they assume I want (or tell me I don't need one).  Even the most detailed I found didn't have an option that suited me.  I'm not looking for a **long** time, but more than ninety days.

One legal option I could figure out was to go as a visa-exempt tourist, and learn enough German (A1 level) to apply for a settlement permit before my ninety days expire.  But the settlement permit requires spending at least 183 days in country.

What other **legal** options are available that **don't** require a job, an expensive school, a lease or purchase on a dwelling, a sponsor, Austria ancestors, or more than six months?  I do have more than enough income for the residence permit.

I know that currently COVID complicates things, but assume I am not blocked by that (which is true as far as I know).

Please don't waste words recommending some illegal method, not even if there's zero chance of getting caught.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to apply for D-Visa (National Visa), for a period up to 12 months and generally cannot be renewed.

For a financially independent person (sufficient funds), properly insured and who does not want to take up residence (but simply wander around the country), this is really the only option.

Such an application must generally be made between 1 and 3 months before the travel date at the responsible consulate or embassy.

It is up to the country itself, on a case by case basis, to decide whether they will issue such a national visa or not.

Comment: Are the requirements for type D  the same for US citizens as for folks from countries that aren't visa-exempt?   The web is full of pages written by people who think no one eligible for visa-exempt could ever want a type D.  But there are few countries where ninety days are enough for my taste.

Comment: @WGroleau As far as financial means and insurance are concerned they will be the same, but must cover the whole period. Basically you must show that you will not cause any harm to the country. There are no general rules for this category.

Comment: "generally cannot be renewed": but for someone who wants to stay for longer than 12 months it can be replaced with a residence permit (as long as the person qualifies for a residence permit, of course; I don't know whether Austria issues residence permits to the financially independent, but some other EU countries certainly do).

Comment: @phoog See changes made to the Schengen Convention Article 18 in [REGULATION (EU) No 265/2010](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02010R0265-20160412#tocId3): *2. Long-stay visas shall have a period of validity **of no more than one year**. If a Member State allows an alien to stay for more than one year, the long-stay visa **shall be replaced** before the expiry of its period of validity by a residence permit.*

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the settlement permit.  But the type D sounds like a better option.  It goes up to a year, which is probably more than enough for me.  And it doesn't prevent me from leaving earlier.

Comment: Settlement permit requires proof of €966 for one person, €1472 for a couple.  Plus health insurance, which can be €200 per month or €600, depending on which web page you believe.  :-)

Comment: @WGroleau A [Niederlassungsbewilligung](https://www.oesterreich.gv.at/themen/leben_in_oesterreich/aufenthalt/3/2/Seite.120310.html) (and is a residence permit **type**), which I assume you mean with 'settlement permit', is intended for persons who already have another residence permit type in Austria (self-employed or highly talented) **or** have certain types of residence permits from other EU member states. This really doesn't match your situation at all.

Comment: @WGroleau The monthly sum needed, **after** reduction of basic monthly costs (rent, insurance etc.), is listed here: [Allgemeine Voraussetzungen für die Erteilung von Aufenthaltstiteln (SDG)](https://www.oesterreich.gv.at/themen/leben_in_oesterreich/aufenthalt/3/Seite.120217.html#Vor) and changes on the 1st of January each year (2021: €1000.48).

Comment: Looked at about six pages that called it a "settlement permit" and said it was the "easiest way to retire in Austria" and that you can apply in country or at a consulate.  Only one listed any requirements, but if they were out of date, I'm not surprised.  My German is not even close to A1 yet, so pages in German aren't helpful.  I can run them through Google Translate, but that is not to be trusted.